# How do you securely delete httpOnly cookies previously used for login?

Tags: cookies, confidentiality, node.js

I am using Angular 8 with Node.js (Express.js) to make a login system. It needs to be secure. I have set the cookies using `httpOnly:true`, which contain a JWT token and it should be deleted by the server-side, since httpOnly cookies can only be deleted by the user manually (not an option) or by the Web Server.

How do I accomplish this successfully? Should I somehow redirect to a page which deletes cookies upon clicking on logout? Proof of concept would be great.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are looking for because you have all the details in your question. Http-only cookies can't be deleted client side so you have to send the user to a page (aka `/logout`) where the back end application will delete the cookie. You've already answered your own question. What else are you looking for?

Comment: @ConorMancone Is the method to accomplish this secure? Only CSRF is an attack surface?

Comment: The problem with JWT tokens is that they can't be invalidated easily. Deleting it doesn't invalidate it.

Comment: @MechMK1 but they have server-side expiration checking (which I implemented) or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you cannot,
you have make another request to backend from there you can remove the cookies.